# DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle and Command Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

In the XAML below, the command property is correctly working only with Column B. Clicking on Column A's header is not invoking command's execute method. The difference is that in Column B, DataGridColumnHeader is instantiated explicitly.

On other hand, the second part of style, the trigger that sets background base on Pressed state is working for both columns.

Why does the Command property work with Column B & not with Column A ?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Test" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">

                    <Setter Property="Command" 
                            Value="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" 
                            Value="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>

                    <Style.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>

                </Style>

            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="12" 
                                    Header="Column A" 
                                    Width="200" 
                                    Binding="{Binding AData}" />

                <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="12" 
                                    Width="200" 
                                    Binding="{Binding BData}">

                    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridColumnHeader Content="Column B" />                                            
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Header
                        >
                </DataGridTextColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

**EDIT**

Data context:

```
namespace TestColumnHeaderCommandBinding
{

    public class Item
    {
        public int AData { get; set; }
        public string BData { get; set; }

    }


    public class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(parameter.ToString() + " clicked");
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class DataContext
    {

        public DataContext()
        {
            MyCommand = new TestColumnHeaderCommandBinding.MyCommand();


            Items = new List<Item>(5);

            Items.Add(new Item { AData = 1, BData = "One" });
            Items.Add(new Item { AData = 2, BData = "Two" });
            Items.Add(new Item { AData = 3, BData = "Three" });
            Items.Add(new Item { AData = 4, BData = "Four" });
            Items.Add(new Item { AData = 5, BData = "Five" });
        }



        public MyCommand MyCommand { get; set; }


        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your viewmodel please so we test on same data as you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't explicitly specify the content of the header, it will just contain a simple string, which will not inherit the `DataContext` of the containing `DataGrid`.

You should see a warning in the Visual Studio output window containing something like this:

```
'MyCommand' property not found on 'object' ''String'
```

To fix that, you can make the binding target the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`:

```
<Setter Property="Command" 
        Value="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand,
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. May I ask why background property works fine for the instance of string ? I still have problems to fully understand it :)

Comment: I think the _style_ works in both cases. It is setting the Command property of both columns to `MyCommand` bindings. The problem is that when you don't specifiy the `DataGridColumnHeader`, the binding will look for a `MyBinding` property on the string, which it can't find. So the whole style works fine, but the binding in the style-setter doesn't.