# Datagridview header click event with MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

On Click of WPF `GridView` header, I need to invoke a particular method instead of default sorting.
I'm doing my project using `MVVM`.
How can I bind a command in my `viewmodel` to `gridview`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this answer on stackoverflow itself. Visit following link.

Source - [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748631/datagrid-columnheaderstyle-and-command-binding)